# Дайте совет как получить матрицу с зеркальным отражением относительно главной диагонали матрицы?

Tags: java

На входе известно только, что матрица квадратная и ее размерность.

Я понял как получить нули на диагонали:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == j) {matrix[i][j] = 0;}
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
       matrix[i][j] = abs(i - j);
```

Comment: спасибо, я честно долго искал решение где то час, потом сдался

Comment: Смотрите - одинаковые числа же лежат на диагоналях, числа есть расстояние от главной диагонали, разность  координат

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix[i][i]=0;
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = j-i;
        matrix[j][i] = j-i;
    }
}
```

Comment: да, зеркально получилось, но не как в примере

Comment: там под диагональю единицы

Comment: исправил формулу.

Comment: спасибо, я бы не догадался